Error when testing xUnit inserting a user into the database
I'm new to writing unit testing
I'm trying to write a unit test for inserting a user into a database but I'm getting an error
Error: System.NotSupportedException : Type to mock (SqlConnection) must be an interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.
I have a UserRepository class:
public class UserRepository : IUSerRepository
{
    public async Task<int> InsertUserAsync(User user, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        
        if (!await UserExistAsync(user.Email!, connection, transaction))
        {
            
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO users (FLO, email) VALUES (@Flo, @Email);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", connection, transaction))
            {
                
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flo", user.Flo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);

                object? res = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                return Convert.ToInt32(res);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = @Email", connection, transaction))
            {
                
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);
                
                object? res = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                
                return Convert.ToInt32(res);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> UserExistAsync(string userEmail, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE email = @Email", connection, transaction))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userEmail);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());
            return count > 0;
        }
    }
}

I need to test his methods
I wrote the following class for tests, so far only 1 method, but received an error message
Test class:
public class UserRepositoryTests
{
    private readonly Mock<SqlConnection> _mockConnection;
    private readonly Mock<SqlTransaction> _mockTransaction;
    private readonly UserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserRepositoryTests()
    {
        _mockConnection = new Mock<SqlConnection>();
        _mockTransaction = new Mock<SqlTransaction>();
        _userRepository = new UserRepository();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task UserRepository_InsertUserAsync_ShouldInsertNewUser_WhenUserDoesNotExist()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockCommand = new Mock<SqlCommand>();
        mockCommand.Setup(cmd => cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync()).ReturnsAsync(1);

        var mockUser = new User { Flo = "Иванов Иван Иванович", Email = "abc@email.com" };

        var mockConnection = new Mock<SqlConnection>();
        var mockTransaction = new Mock<SqlTransaction>();

        var userRepository = new Mock<UserRepository>();
        userRepository.Setup(repo => repo.UserExistAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<SqlConnection>(), It.IsAny<SqlTransaction>()))
                      .ReturnsAsync(false); // Пользователь не существует

        // Act
        int result = await userRepository.Object.InsertUserAsync(mockUser, mockConnection.Object, mockTransaction.Object);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(1, result);
    }
}


UserRepository is the unit under test and should not need to be mocked. Any local method called by the method being tested should be executed and be part of the test. Instead of working around the problem not being able to mock SQLCommand, see it as an indicator that UserRepository is tighly coupled and either UserExistAsync() can be moved into something you inject into UserRepository that executes commands or you look into injecting IDbCommand or IDbConnection if possible. Bandaids/workarounds usually hide the long term problem which will eventually have to be addressed anyway.

I don't understand a little where can I transfer UserExistAsync()? What did you mean by that?

SqlCommand, SqlConnection and SqlTransaction are all sealed classes. You can't mock those. Alternative is to use IdbConnection and IdbTransaction create the command from the connection using (var cmd = (SqlCommand)connection.CreateCommand()){...} assigning the transaction inside like this: cmd.Transaction = (SqlTransaction)transaction; - This However, will start causing you issues with MoQ as it creates Castle.Proxies.IDbCommandProxy which can't be cast to a sqlCommand. HENCE, wrap your commands in a custom ICommandRunner and inject that into the Repo class. Easy to mock.

The ICommandRunner or what ever you want to call it, then has method inside it like GetUser, AddUser, UserExists etc... You still want to use IdbConnection and IdbTransaction in the ICommandRunner is possible but if all you do is execute commands in that class it needs no unit tests, though it might need integration tests.
Now for the Repo tests you can mock ICommandRunner setup GetUser, AddUser, UserExists  as needed and Bob is you uncle.

Issue

System.NotSupportedException : Type to mock (SqlConnection) must be an
interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.

This error is telling you that Moq is not able to create a mock for SqlConnection as it is a sealed class.
SqlCommand, SqlConnection and SqlTransaction are all sealed classes and Moq will not be able to mock them.
IDb... Interfaces
You can work against the interfaces and in your UserRepository class you could use IDbConnection and IDbTransaction instead.
You create the command from the connection then instead await using (var cmd = (SqlCommand)_connection.CreateCommand()){...}
The problem is Moq, when creating the setup for CreateCommand() Moq creates Castle.Proxies.IDbCommandProxy which can't be cast to SqlCommand
Abstracting Command Execution
I find the easiest is to abstract the command execution away from the repository. Your repository class has logic that needs to be tested but you don't need to test the command execution.
You can create a class which runs your commands and inject that into your repository instead. then you can mock that easily and test your logic.
In my example I named the interface ICommandRunner and implementation SqlCommandRunner but you can name it which ever you like best.
I used IDb interfaces but you don't have to.
public interface ICommandRunner
{
    Task<int> InsertUserAsync(User user);
    Task<int> GetUserIdByEmailAsync(string userEmail);
    Task<bool> UserExistAsync(string userEmail);
}

public sealed class SqlCommandRunner : ICommandRunner
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;
    private readonly IDbTransaction _transaction;

    public SqlCommandRunner(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _transaction = transaction;
    }

    public async Task<int> InsertUserAsync(User user)
    {
        await using (var cmd = (SqlCommand)_connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (FLO, email) VALUES (@Flo, @Email);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
            cmd.Transaction = (SqlTransaction)_transaction;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flo", user.Flo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", user.Email);

            var res = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

            return Convert.ToInt32(res);
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<int> GetUserIdByEmailAsync(string userEmail)
    {
        await using (var cmd = (SqlCommand)_connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = @Email";
            cmd.Transaction = (SqlTransaction)_transaction;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userEmail);

            var res = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

            return Convert.ToInt32(res);
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<bool> UserExistAsync(string userEmail)
    {
        await using (var cmd = (SqlCommand)_connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE email = @Email";
            cmd.Transaction = (SqlTransaction)_transaction;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userEmail);

            var count = Convert.ToInt32(await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync());

            return count > 0;
        }
    }
}

You can now inject that into your UserRepository and use it instead.
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly ICommandRunner _commandRunner;

    public UserRepository(ICommandRunner commandRunner)
    {
        _commandRunner = commandRunner;
    }

    public async Task<int> InsertUserAsync(User user)
    {
        if (!await UserExistAsync(user.Email!))
        {
            return await _commandRunner.InsertUserAsync(user);
        }

        return await _commandRunner.GetUserIdByEmailAsync(user.Email!);
    }

    public async Task<bool> UserExistAsync(string userEmail)
    {
        return await _commandRunner.UserExistAsync(userEmail);
    }
}

Easier Unit Testing
Your unit tests can now focus on the logic in the repository.
public class UserRepositoryTests
{
    private readonly Mock<ICommandRunner> _mockCommandRunner;
    private readonly UserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserRepositoryTests()
    {
        _mockCommandRunner = new Mock<ICommandRunner>();
        _userRepository = new UserRepository(_mockCommandRunner.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task UserRepository_InsertUserAsync_ShouldInsertNewUser_WhenUserDoesNotExist()
    {
        // Arrange
        var user = new User { Flo = "Иванов Иван Иванович", Email = "abc@email.com" };

        _mockCommandRunner
            .Setup(cr => cr.UserExistAsync(user.Email))
            .ReturnsAsync(false);
        
        _mockCommandRunner
            .Setup(cr => cr.InsertUserAsync(user))
            .ReturnsAsync(1);

        // Act
        var result = await _userRepository.InsertUserAsync(user);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(1, result);

        _mockCommandRunner.Verify(cr => cr.UserExistAsync(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
        _mockCommandRunner.Verify(cr => cr.InsertUserAsync(It.IsAny<User>()), Times.Once);
    }
}

Summary
The above is just an example how to decouple from the command execution and not having to worry about mocking sealed classes or IDb interfaces.
The solution might not fit your specific situation but hopefully helped somewhat, allowing yout to solve the testing problem you encountered.
You still execute the commands in the SqlCommandRunner but that simply executes the commands. You still want integration test but no unit tests are needed for it.

I mainly used your current setup as much as possible but if you want the command execution to stay in the UserRepository you can move the logic away from the Repository instead. You can move the logic into a UserService class, injecting the UserRepository into the service class.  Then you simply write the unit tests against the UserService class instead.

Did I understand correctly that it is better to use integration testing in my situation?

Unit tests are fine as you mock everything. I was just referring to integration tests in general in addition to unit tests if you want to verify that your code interacts with the database as expected, etc... It was just a general comment :)

The error message already tells you what is wrong:

System.NotSupportedException : Type to mock (SqlConnection) must be an interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.

This is as expected, because Moq doesn't do anything you can't do by hand.
In this case, the UserExistAsync method isn't virtual, and while the class implements an interface, that's not what the test is 'mocking'.
Rather, this creates a 'mock' of a concrete class, and not the interface:
var userRepository = new Mock<UserRepository>();

While a bit unusual, it looks as though you're using a SUT Double. If that's your intent, you'll need to make the method virtual:
public virtual async Task<bool> UserExistAsync(
    string userEmail,
    SqlConnection connection,
    SqlTransaction transaction)

